# Check python var if int

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, int

I am trying to get python to check if a certain variable is an int

```
    numbergames = input("Number of Games to Analyze: ")
valuenumber = True
while valuenumber == True:
    if numbergames == int:
        valuenumber = False
    if numbergames != int:
        numbergames = input("Please type a valid number: ")
print("Thanks")
```

The code is getting stuck and is not getting out of the loop even thought the number typed is an int.

Comment: `int` is a `type`, not an instance of an integer. use `isinstance(numbergames,int)`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: For how to deal with user input, take a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/1977847

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is discouraged to use `type()` as identifying if an input is int, float, etc. This is because it does not register a subclass of `int` as an `int`.

Instead, use `isinstance('var', (int, long))` which will give the right result expected. So your code will take the form of:

```
numberGames = input("Number of Games to Analyze: ")

while True:
    if isinstance( numberGames, (int, long) ):
        break
    else:
        numberGames = input("Please type a valid number: ")
print("Thanks")
```

You don't need the `valueNumber` variable because its only use is as a flag for the while loop. Instead, it could continue running indefinitely with `True` until it reaches `break` because the statement tells the program to exit the loop.